# Linker error with Lua and vs2015

Tags: c++, lua, visual-studio-2015

I'm very new to using visual studio, and c++.

I was trying to build a game to test my OOP understandings using new language, then I realized I might need to start using scripting language with in my C++ game. I found LUA to be a good candidate for the scripting part of the game, so I decided to follow a tutorial I've found at :
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/the-lua-tutorial-r2999

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <lua.hpp> 
#include<iostream>


int main()
{
 char *Lua =
    "x = 8 "
    "return ( x > 7 ) ";

 lua_State *luaState;

 luaState = luaL_newstate();
 int iStatus = luaL_loadstring(luaState, szLua);
 if (iStatus)
 {
    std::cout << "Error: " << lua_tostring(luaState, -1);
    return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

However VS 2015 debugger is giving

```
 unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate
 unresolved external symbol _luaL_loadstring
 unresolved external symbol _lua_tolstring
```

I'm currently using Lua 5.1.5, and followed the tutorial setting tutorial section step by step, where it tells me to add lua folders to project settings.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add either the library (under project settings), or the source code?

Comment: @immibis Could you be a bit more specific? I am very new to this and linker compiler settings are quite daunting for me atm. I've added some folders, as specified in the tutorial, to c/c++ general section. However nothing to linker settings

Comment: Lua has some code in it; how does the linker know where to find the code?

Comment: @immibis Are you suggesting that I should add lua folders to linker setting as well? I've tried what I deemed to be right thing to do. Now my settings under c/c++ general/additional include directories include path_to_lua\src, path_to_lua\etc. Under linker/general/additional library directories I have the same. Still the same issue, although I don't think this is what i'm supposed to be doing.

Comment: @immibs the Lua package i've downloaded only contains etc, src, doc, test folders. I imagine only etc and src are the ones in question here.

Comment: @immibs do I need to build Lua first?

Comment: @user3442960: "*I am very new to this*" If you are very new to linking a library into your executable, then perhaps Lua is not something you're ready to be doing.

Comment: @NicolBolas how else would i start learning. Besides I've done linking libraries to my executable before. It doesn't seem to have a library to execute from the package i've downloaded. Looks like I will have to build it first

Comment: @user3442960 I believe Lua is designed to be simple enough that you can just add the source files to your project (as if they were your own source files) and it'll work.

Comment: @immibis I've now managed to build Lua into dll and libraries using vs command prompt and managed to get it work. I didn't understand what you meant earlier because I've never used VS before and thought the settings somehow magically find the library files and compile them together via settings (imagined it to be something like java and eclipse). I can confirm now what you've told me works as well. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @immibis Thank you very much for your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker errors indicate that you are missing Lua functions from the executable you want to build. It's possible that you missed this step in the tutorial you've been following: `add the Lua source files to your project's "Source Files". There is a list of the files in C:\dev\lua-5.1.5\etc\all.c; you want all of those files except for lua.c.`

In general, you need to add the Lua library, lua DLL, or Lua files (in this case it's not enough to specify path to them), so that the references for the functions you are using in your code are properly resolved (statically or dynamically).

Comment: this works too. However I managed to read some tutorials on how to create libs and dlls using visual studio command prompt and built the files.  I can't believe this simple solution (copying files) existed, but then it's my first time using VS. Anywas I now won't need to copy Lua into projects, but I've selected your answer because it is just as good a solution. Thank you for your reply